# Difference between packed position vs flat position android expandable listview

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am confused between flat position and packed position of expandable listview. I searched on Google but what I found is

> Flat list position: The position used by ListView and its adapters
>
> Packed position: A long that "packs" (bit twiddling) what type of
> position (group, child, or null for headers/footers) as well as the
> position value(s) (group/child values)

But still I am not able to understand it perfectly. It would be great if someone explain me with example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Found solution myself:**

Flat position is the index of the view on the screen no matter what type (child or group). Like shown in this image

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY50q.png)

Whereas packed position is a long which has few values like type of view (child or group) and flat position of the view encoded using binary operators(like and `&`, or `|`, shift `<<` or `>>`).

Answer (score 0):

Expandable List View:

Expandable list view is used to group list data by categories. It has the capability of expanding and collapsing the groups when user touches header.

In order to create an expandable list view, we need three xml layout files. First one is for main listview, 2nd one for list view group item and 3rd one is for list view child item.

Create a new class file called ExpandableListAdapter.java and extend this from BaseExpandableListAdapter. This class provides required methods to render listview.

```
getGroupView() – Returns view for the list group header
getChildView() – Returns view for list child item
```

for Creating Adapter you have to create DataList for ExpandableListView like below:

```
* Preparing the list data
     */
    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("OS");
        listDataHeader.add("LANGUAGE");
        listDataHeader.add("IDE");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> OS= new ArrayList<String>();
        OS.add("Windows");
        OS.add("Linux");
        OS.add("Android");
        OS.add("MAC");


        List<String> LANGUAGE= new ArrayList<String>();
        LANGUAGE.add("JAVA");
        LANGUAGE.add("C");
        LANGUAGE.add("C++");
        LANGUAGE.add("PHP");
        LANGUAGE.add("objective c");
        LANGUAGE.add("ROR");

        List<String> IDE= new ArrayList<String>();
        IDE.add("Android Studio");
        IDE.add("Eclipse");
        IDE.add("NetBeans");
        IDE.add("xcode");


        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), OS); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), LANGUAGE);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), IDE);
    }
```

Please find more details to understand Expandable List View

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: This is good information, but the question was about packed position vs. flat position.